# iphone x and lens for camera - should I be worried about scratches

Tags: iphone, camera

I just got a new iPhone X and am curious if I should protect it from scratching the lens. I am using an Element Case to protect but is this enough for the lens of the camera too? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most [surface scratches on any camera lens don’t matter](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/) a huge amount due to how light focuses. That being said, you’ll want to not scuff too badly or crack the housing. Apple has had a long time to get the hardness right on the glass and cameras, so I would expect you’d have a low chance of issues - especially if you have a case.

Drops to the body (to the ground from a table / case or not) and internal failure are much more likely to compromise image quality than a physical failure of the lens.

Also note - even without a case, the physica of the metal band surrounding the camera make it very hard to hit the part of the glass where the sensor / light enter. Nothing is going to stop an ice pick or diamond ring that targets “ground zero” on the cover, but most unintentional drops and scrapes should be away from the light path by design.

Comment: thx - hmmm - I have a few photography who would probably take issue with your first sentence :) But thx - that's a bit what I figured. I guess now that there > 1k phones and the main reason for my getting a new one was the camera, that this isn't offered. I got this case https://www.elementcase.com/rev-iphone-x-case.html and am happy with it.

Comment: @timpone Clearly the "right" scratch in the "right" place can be very harmful. Most scratches in most places, though - especially ones on the small glass face that don't entirely break / shatter the iPhone is not a deal breaker for most photos.

Comment: @timpone - it is quite a common misconception that scratches on the front element of a lens badly affect the image. This is about the most conclusive proof you'll ever need that it's really an unfounded fear, from Roger Cicala at Lensrentals - https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2008/10/front-element-scratches/